# Using Lucee from java

Tags: java, coldfusion, lucee

Currently trying to create a way for my java project to call ColdFusion methods. I have stumbled upon [Lucee](http://docs.lucee.org/guides/working-with-source/java-using-lucee-in-java.html) but I'm having trouble getting the imports to work properly within a maven java project. It just does not find the javax.* dependencies. Also the Cookie is giving me the Abstract error, and I don't really want to implement about 20+  methods.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import lucee.loader.engine.CFMLEngine;
import lucee.loader.engine.CFMLEngineFactory;
import lucee.runtime.PageContext;
import lucee.runtime.type.scope.Cookie;

public class Controller{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        CFMLEngine engine = CFMLEngineFactory.getInstance();
        javax.servlet.http.Cookie[] cookies = new Cookie[]{new Cookie("myCookie","myCookieValue")};
        Map<String, Object> headers=new HashMap();
        headers.put("accept","text/html");
        Map<String, String> parameters=new HashMap();
        Map<String, Object> attributes=new HashMap();
        PageContext pc = engine.createPageContext(
                "localhost"
                ,"/index.cfm"
                ,"test=1"
                ,cookies
                ,headers
                ,parameters
                ,attributes
                ,System.out
                ,50000
                ,true
                );
        try{
            }
        finally{
            engine.releasePageContext(pc, true/* unregister the pc from the thread*/);
        }
  }
}
```

This was taken directly from the Lucee docs, so I'm pretty sure the code is correct. Sadly it doesn't seem to explain the correct imports to use. So I'm currently at a confused state and figuring this out.

Is my import correct? or have I derped and used the wrong ones?

Edit 1: I tried downloading and adding the [Javax.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxjar.htm) but that alters the parameters that Pagecontext wants. As I'm still new to Lucee, I'm not too comfortable altering too much of the given code (nor do I feel like I should need to).

Comment: Doing some guessing here, but both of those classes (Cookie and PageContext) appear to come from javax.servlet.*. If you downloaded Lucee, the servlet jar should be included, `servlet-api.jar`.  Even with those adjustments, I couldn't get the example to run with Lucee 5.2.x. So either we're both missing something or the docs are out of synch.  If you don't get an answer here, try cfml slack, someone there might now. https://cfml-slack.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Thanks Ageax, glad I wasn’t the only one having this issue, I’ll do as you’ve advised and head to that slack group. I’ll update this question with an answer if I managed to get one from there.

Comment: Any luck on the slack channel?

Comment: Ah terribly sorry, completely skipped my mind that I had asked the question here. We decided to take a different approach so we won’t use lucre now. Sadly I didn’t get a reply on slack either.

Comment: Bummer, was hoping someone there would know. Anyway, thanks for following up :)